# Close all running apps at one time in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

How to close all running/open apps at one time in Windows 10? I had tried some blog said open Task Manager > Select all Processes > End Task. However, wins10 now seems like not allowed to select multiple processes.

Comment: This is not about programming.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `cmd` but it is a little painful here's the explanation:

1 - run `cmd` as Administrator

2 - type the command `tasklist` and press Enter

3 - Now you can see all currently running programs.

4 - Now you need to use a command called `TASKKILL` and use the `PID` of every program to close.

Let's imagine if a program have `PID = 21093`

You'll need to use this command:

`TASKKILL /PID 21093 /F`

And this goes for all the `PID's` like this:

`TASKKILL /PID 21093 1048 1592 1040 /F`

PS: `/F` means forcibly terminate

Comment: If I need to know all the task's PID. that will be very troublesome

Comment: the task's PID appear on cmd after you run the tasklist command, you'll just need to write  all of them

Comment: what I want to achieve is the most simplest/convinient way to close all running apps for time saving purpose